# How can I connect a sub-panel to an unused 60A breaker in another panel?

Tags: subpanel

So I have a contractor installing a gas furnace where I used to have an electric furnace. I am ending up with a 60a circuit that is not needed anymore. I want to take that circuit and install a subpanel so I can run two or more 15 or 20a circuits off it. Should be able to do that no problem. But where I am confused is instead of having a black and red wire I have a black a white and a bare wire. How do I wire that into my panel?

Comment: Is replacing the wiring run an option here, or would only having 120V be a problem for that matter?

Comment: can you settle for ONLY powering 120V  circuits off that panel?

Comment: Ya that’s all I want is 120 like two or three 15 or 20 amp 120 circuits.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I think replacing the wire would be really hard it’s a long run and it’s finished from start to end.

Comment: @ChadBarker -- what make and model is your main panel?

Comment: It's a little tricky but doable, one of us will be able to write up something tonight or tomorrow.  You'll need to move it to one 120V breaker in the main panel and white becomes real  neutral,

Comment: Shouldn’t the white and black both have 120v other wise where is that other 120 going? I know that’s not the normal.

Comment: If your furnace was 240v the white was the other hot phase. It will become the neutral, as Harper said, when you connect to a 120v breaker in the main panel.

Comment: So what was the negative feed? The problem is I do it the way mentioned above I lose a lot of amps don’t I. I mean to my knowledge there is not 60a 120v breakers.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use just one side of the existing breaker and leave the other unused?

Comment: You don't necessarily lose amperage. You can use a 1-pole breaker and get 60A, but you're limited to 120V outlets (which isn't much of a limitation in reality). 1-pole, 60A breakers exist (https://www.homedepot.com/p/Siemens-60-Amp-Single-Pole-Type-QP-Circuit-Breaker-Q160/206632137), though your manufacturer may or may not make them. There is no "negative feed," only two hot legs (at 120V each from neutral and 240V from each other).

Comment: So I can replace the double pole with a single pole. Make black my positive and white the negative and bare the ground. But then when I wire the sub panel only one side of the panel will work. Or am I missing something?

Comment: My main breaker box is a GE powermark gold. The breaker I am working with is actually two 60a breakers tied together with a bar.  So can I just remove the bar and do as talked about above? How will I wire that so all spaces in the new box work and not every other one.

Comment: I get where you're going, but it's time to learn the right words. There is a) **safety earthing** which is only for safety and never normally handles current, called ground but nothing like the DC electronics meaning of the word ; b) **neutral**, which is deliberately pegged to be very near earth potential *and defined as such*, and unfused; and c) **hot**, which is a conductor *not* near earth potential.  There can be several hots, but you need white for neutral, leaving only one.  Ground can never be neutral.  Your old furnace didn't need neutral, that's why white was used for hot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Make this a 120V only subpanel

Since the original circuit was 240V-only (hot, hot, ground), you're short the neutral wire needed for having both 120 *and* 240V at the old furnace's location.  Since you only *need* 120V here, though, what you *can* do is install a 120V-only subpanel; however, that limits you to 50A as 120V-only (by design) subpanels don't come in larger sizes, and trying to use a larger subpanel gets confusing, what with the potential for skipped slots and all.

You'll need a GE THQL1150 breaker (to replace the THQL2160 that's in there right now), a TQLFP1 filler plate to fill the hole left by the other pole, a Square-D QO24L50TTS panel for your subpanel, a suitable NM clamp for the cable coming in, and appropriate QO single pole or QOT double-stuff branch breakers in 15 and 20A, as well as a torque screwdriver or torque wrench that goes up to 50 inch pounds or so as all lugs *must* be torqued to their manufacturer specification (110.14(D) in the 2017 NEC).  Replace the THQL2160 with the THQL1150 (with the main off) -- the black wire that landed on the THQL2160 lands on the THQL1150's lug, the white wire that landed on the THQL2160 gets moved over to land on the neutral bar (torque it to spec too!) as it will be a neutral now, not the other hot leg, and the bare wire stays put as it will continue to be a ground.  Snap the TQLFP1 into the hole in the deadfront left where the other half of the THQL2160 was.

Once this is done, leave the new branch breaker off, button the main panel up, and turn the main breaker back on.  You can then mount and install the QO24L50TTS in an appropriate spot; once it's mounted and the cable fed in through a KO and secured, you then can terminate the black wire from the cable to the main lug, the white wire from the cable to a lug on the neutral bar on the far right, and the bare wire from the cable to a lug on the ground bar on the far left.  Make sure to torque the connections to spec; there will be no bonding strap or bonding screw to pull, as the QO24L50TTS is not suitable for use as service equipment to begin with.

Then, you can install the appropriate OQ or QOT single pole breakers (QO115/120 or QOT1515/1520/2020 depending on the mix of 15 and 20A circuits you need, you can get 4 circuits max using double-stuffs in this panel) and wire up your 15 and 20A circuits to the subpanel.  Note that if you want ground-fault or arc-fault protection here, it will probably be easiest to use a short conduit nipple over to a box with a deadfront GFCI, AFCI, or DFCI in it instead of crimping your circuit count with a GFCI, AFCI, or DFCI breaker.

Comment: Wow that’s very detailed. Thank you! This will leave a gap in my main box correct? If so I guess just get a spacer to put back in?

Comment: @ChadBarker -- it will, you'll need a TQLFP1 spacer to fill it

Comment: Or another breaker.  Breakers hooked to nothing make exemplary blanking plates, and are useful if you ever add a circuit, which blanking plates are not.   Now TPE, is there a code prohibition on simply using every other slot on a 120/240 panel or splitting the one hot and feeding both panel legs?

Comment: @Harper -- using every other slot on a 120/240 panel isn't *wrong*, but it is potentially *confusing* to the next bloke.  Feeding both busbars in parallel is...also potentially confusing (in a worse way, even).

Comment: I have the panel you suggested above ordered because I couldn’t find it anywhere locally. I have a quick question however is this 120 only box so there is only one positive lug? I guess what I am asking is will I still have to skip slots as it only has two that’s not ideal.

Comment: @ChadBarker -- yeah, it only has one line lug/busbar, so you won't have to skip any slots

Comment: So the existing wire does not quite reach a wall where I could put the load center can I put a small box and use wire nuts to add a few feet of wire to get it to where I would like the load center? I know it’s not ideal but I don’t see another way unless I was to put the load center on the ceiling lol

Comment: @ChadBarker -- go ahead and use a box and wirenuts to splice in an additional length of the same size cable

Comment: So next question is it even possible to get wirenuts for 6 gauge wire?

Comment: @ChadBarker -- instead of wirenuts, a mechanical tap connector ("Polaris connector") like one of [these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Polaris-4-14-AWG-Bagged-Insulated-Tap-Connector-Black-IT-4AB/303579042) is used  with such large wire

Comment: Could one of these be used? [splice connector](http://2-Count%20Splice%20Wire%20Connectors%20https://www.lowes.com/pd/2-Count-Splice-Wire-Connectors/4618524)

Comment: @ChadBarker -- I'd call it a wee bit on the big side (and also needful of a heat gun to install)...

Comment: I ordered the one you suggested. Thanks for all you help! The subpanel won’t be here for another week but I hope to get everything else wired up before that and then just place the subpanel and pop in the breakers and be done. I only plan on doing a 15 and 20 amp for now one for some outlets and one for two ceiling fans.